# Castle Windsor Cannot find my Service Type

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Trying to make use of the Castle Windsor IoC. I have a very simple application. My interfaces exist in Test.Services namespace. I get the following exception when compiling:

"The type name Test.Services.IParse, Test.Services could not be located"

This is my app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle"
      type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,    
      Castle.Windsor" />


   </configSections>

  <castle>
    <components>
      <component id="HtmlTitleRetriever"
                 type="Test.HTMLTitleRetriever, Test">
      </component>
      <component id="FileParser"
                 service="Test.Services.IParse, Test.Services"
                 type="Test.FileParser,   
                      Test">
      </component>
      <component id="FileDownloader"
                 service="Test.Services.IDownload, Test.Services"
                 type="Test.FileDownloader, Test">
      </component>
    </components>
  </castle>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

-Nick

Answer (score 2):

Stupid question, but are you certain that the assembly containing the class you register gets actually copied to the output directory?

Comment: It's not a stupid question at all. It can easily be done, if you don't have a reference to the assembly containing your service then it won't exist in the output folder.

Comment: I know. I'm just making sure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.AddComponent("FileDownlader", typeof(IDownload),
             typeof(FileDownloader));
        container.AddComponent("FileParser", typeof(IParse),
             typeof(FileParser));
        container.AddComponent("HTMLTitleRetriever", typeof(HTMLTitleRetriever));

        HTMLTitleRetriever retriever = container.Resolve<HTMLTitleRetriever>();
```

Doing the following in code works. I would like to use a Config file though so changes do not need to be recompiled each time.

Comment: Doing the following in code works, because now you have hard dependency on all assemblies and compiler ensures they are accessible. My question still stands - do you copy the Test.Services.dll to the output directory when using config file? Notice that the compiler will not do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Almost Nick!  You need to pass the xml configuration into the constructor of WindsorContainer:

```
IWindsorContainer container;
container =
  new WindsorContainer(
    new XmlInterpreter(
      new ConfigResource("castle")
  ));
```

I ran into this "Got ya" as well when I first started playing with Castle Windsor.  It does not know to look into the configuration section.

Tip: go get the latest from their trunk.  There's a new method called Register that is really useful for mass-registering multiple classes on the same interface.  I.e., if you are developing with ASP.NET MVC, and you have a bunch of IController, you can use Castle Windsor to auto-register them for you. So, you do not have to specify them in the configuration file!

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : IControllerFactor
{
  IWindsorContainer container;
  public WindsorControllerFactory()
  {
    container =
      new WindsorContainer(
        new XmlInterpreter(
          new ConfigResource("castleWindsor")
      ));

    container.Register(
      AllTypes.Of<IController>()
      .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
      .Configure(component => component.LifeStyle.Transient
        .Named(component.Implementation.Name)
      ));
  }
}
```

Comment: IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));

I tried this.. Same issue. I am checking the obviouse and I see no typos. "Cannot find the type Test.Services.IParse"

Comment: Could you update your question with actual code?  You have to ensure your namespaces and assembly names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is the IParse interface in the Test.Services assembly (Test.Services.dll) ?

The format used to define type names in the config is the same you can get from the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx#) property of the type. In a nutshell, it's:

Namespace.Type, Assembly.

For generic types, see [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/2006/05/15/TheNatureOfGenericTypeNames.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and Eric's solution worked to resolve the problem. I Created a "Domain Models" Project and then later renamed it to "DomainModel" I though I changed all the references but then looking in the bin folder the assembly was still called "Domain Models" thats why castle windsor could not find it.

Comment: Cool.  :)  (Name is now eduncan911, not Eric)