# Castle Windsor cannot find System.Messaging

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I realise this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624310/castle-windsor-cannot-find-my-service-type), but unfortunately it doesn't quite solve my problem.

I have a console app with the following in my castle config section:

```
<component id="LegacyMessageFormatter" 
           service="System.Messaging.IMessageFormatter, System.Messaging" 
           type="MsmqLogProcessor.Core.Services.LegacyMessageFormatter, MsmqLogProcessor.Core"/>
```

I initially got an exception "The type name System.Messaging.IMessageFormatter, System.Messaging could not be located." when newing up my WindsorContainer like so:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
```

I've set Copy Local to true on System.Messaging. That works when I hit F5.
However, when I publish my console app and run it on a production box I get the same issue. I cannot see the System.Messaging dll in the ApplicationFiles folder after install, presumably because it thinks it's in the GAC.

I've tried copying the dll into this folder, but still no joy.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Is it even a good idea to specify a System assembly as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the fully qualified type name:

```
<component id='LegacyMessageFormatter' 
service='System.Messaging.IMessageFormatter, System.Messaging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
type='...'/>
```

Comment: Woohoo. That did it! More elegant than rolling your own ConversionManager. Cheers mate.

Comment: By the way, what is the significance of using the fully qualified type name? Why does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Windsor does not lookup types in System assemblies, as you can see here
https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/SubSystems/Conversion/TypeNameConverter.cs#L170

it explicitly skips types defined in assemblies with a name starting with System.

Don't know why but you can workaround this by using your own ConversionManager

```
public class MyConversionManager : DefaultConversionManager
{
    protected override void InitDefaultConverters()
    {
        Add(new SystemMessaging_TypeConverter(new TypeNameParser()));

        base.InitDefaultConverters();
    }
}

public class SystemMessaging_TypeConverter : TypeNameConverter
{
    public SystemMessaging_TypeConverter(ITypeNameParser parser) : base(parser)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ShouldSkipAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly)
    {
        return !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("System.Messaging") && base.ShouldSkipAssembly(assembly);
    }
}
```

and install it in your container as follows:

```
    var container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Kernel.AddSubSystem(SubSystemConstants.ConversionManagerKey, new MyConversionManager());

    container.Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
```

And then register the service **without** the assembly name:

```
<component id="LegacyMessageFormatter"
service="System.Messaging.IMessageFormatter"
type="MsmqLogProcessor.Core.Services.LegacyMessageFormatter, MsmqLogProcessor.Core">
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for that. I had a feeling it was something to do with Castle ignoring System types, but I don't know enough about the guts of Castle to figure it out. Trying this now...